# Etymology of tomoe-nage?

Tags: judo, terminology, japanese, throwing

Tomoe-nage is often translated as "stomach throw" or "circle throw", but these are not direct translations. What does *tomoe* mean, and why is the throw called this?

Comment: Related: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/origin-of-kawazu-gake https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9329/origin-of-kata-guruma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Tomoe* (巴) refers to a circular anti-symmetric symbol commonly found in Japanese heraldry. The usage in the judo throw specifically refers to the two-tailed version, *futatsu-domoe*:

[image]

This is very similar to the Chinese taijitu ("yin-yang" symbol) ☯, or Korean taegeuk (famously appearing on South Korea's flag) .

*Tomoe-nage* is named as such because Kano thought the positioning/movement of tori and uke's bodies resembled this symbol during the throw:

> #### The origin of tomoe-nage
>
> Randori techniques resembling tomoe-nage are found in the jujutsu textbook *Shikatsu Jizai, Sekkotsu Ryoho, Jujutsu Seirisho* as sutemi-tori and tachi-sutemi-tori.
>
> Master Kano bestowed this technique with the name tomoe-nage. In *Judokai chabanashi* (from *Judo*, published by Judo Kai Honbu, 1916), it says:
>
> > "Master Kano was an expert at tomoe-nage. This was originally a Tenjin Shinyo-ryu technique named Ando-gaeshi, after an certain Ando who was skilled in the
> >     technique.
> >
> > It was at that time probably named along with uki-waza, or called Kano-nage or Kano-gaeshi.
> >
> > **Master Kano once said that he named this technique after its resemblance to two objects moving in a circular form"**
>
> - [*Kodokan Judo: Throwing Techniques*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=HGpbICBZdGwC&q=tomoe+nage)

[image] [image]

Comment: Just for the record, I support self answers like this to archive learned knowledge.

Comment: This throw is referred to as *ma-sutemi-nage* in an article on ju-jitsu in this volume of [*Transactions and proceedings of the Japan Society*](https://archive.org/details/transactionsand00londgoog/page/n26) (1892)

Comment: Mifune translates this as "Big comma throw" in his Canon of Judo.