# Origin of kata-guruma?

Tags: judo, history, wrestling, throwing

In an interview with Torahei Ochiai in the 1920's, Jigoro Kano states that he adopted kata-guruma from wrestling's fireman's carry.<sup>1</sup> However, the Kodokan Judo Throwing Techniques book posits a different origin, an adaptation of a koryu jujutsu throw (ostensibly via [Kyutaro Kanda](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ky%C5%ABtar%C5%8D+Kanda)).<sup>2 3</sup>

Do we know **which of these is the true origin of the throw as practised in judo?**

---

**Sources**

1. > I recall another anecdote from my days at the Fukuda dojo. Normally, I did not have a particularly hard time when practicing with Aoki and the other trainees. In the case of Fukushima, however, it was a completely different story. I could not overcome the strength nor disturb the balance of Kanekichi Fukushima no matter how hard or how often I tried. Finally, I resolved that I would learn to throw him somehow or other. After giving the matter a great deal of thought, I decided that a sumo technique might be effective against him. Upon hearing that a former sumo man, Kisoemon Uchiyama, worked at my university dormitory, I requested him to teach me sumo techniques. The sumo throws that I learned from him, however, proved to be totally ineffective against Fukushima. **It then occurred to me to research books on western style wrestling, so I went to my local public library in Yushima, Bunkyo Ward. Unfortunately from among the wrestling books available, there did not seem to be any throw that I could use on Fukushima, except one that I thought just might be effective against him since Fukushima was taller than I. This throw was a shoulder wheel or *kata-guruma*.** I experimented with it on one of my student friends soon after reading about it and succeeded in throwing him. I also tried it on Aoki with the same result. On my next visit to the dojo, therefore, I challenged Fukushima to a practice, and for the first time in my life I successfully threw him with my newly acquired technique. After many months of trying, I had finally managed to down him. I was overjoyed and felt a great sense of achievement.

   - [*Judo Memoirs of Jigoro Kano*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Evjhhr2OsC0C&q=kata-guruma)

> There appears to have been a prototype of kata-guruma in koryu jujutsu.
> Kyutaro Kanda, 9th dan, is widely known as the master of kata-guruma and is thought to have developed the original kata-guruma from kinu-katsugi of the Yoshin-ryu Totsuka school.
> There is also a similar technique in Yoshin-ryu, called hankai-garami. However it is unclear if it has any relation to kata-guruma.
> [image]
> There exists a further technique in sumo wrestling known as [sori-te](https://sumo.sports.smt.docomo.ne.jp/kimarite/sorite.html) (*Sumo wa koshite miru no ga tanoshii*, published by Baseball Magazine Co., 1992).
> [image]

- [*Kodokan Judo Throwing Techniques*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=HGpbICBZdGwC&q=kata-guruma) (p.36-37)

That the throw was introduced to judo via Kanda seems obviously false given kata-guruma was part of the original gokyo-no-waza, standardised in 1895, two years before Kanda's birth.

Comment: Being that this is a very universal kind of throw, it could have come to Judo from multiple different sources at multiple different occasions to multiple different judoka. There doesn't need to be a single source. And I think your evidence shows that is the case. I don't think this is a case of revisionist history, if that's what you might suspect, as a way to de-emphasize the non-Japanese origins of the technique. The answer is probably all of the above.