# Why is a "scarf hold" so-named if you don't wrap around the opponent's neck (like a scarf)?

Tags: judo, terminology, japanese, uniform, pins

Judo's *kesa-gatame* is often translated as "scarf hold", but the technique is defined by wrapping your arms and upper body around uke's neck and arm, more like a seatbelt, as opposed to wrapping around just their neck, like a scarf. Why is it called this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When translating foreign technique names, sometimes there isn't a perfect analogue in the target language e.g. ["tomoe"](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9190/etymology-of-tomoe-nage/9191) in *tomoe-nage* translated as 'circle'.

The "kesa" (袈裟) in *kesa-gatame* in fact refers to a type of buddhist robe, the [Kāṣāya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasaya_(clothing)#Kesa_in_Japanese_Buddhism). While historically it was worn covering both shoulders, in current Japanese Buddhist style it is **wrapped across the body with the right shoulder exposed**, as is the style in which the Buddha is traditionally depicted:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

---

> <sup>***Kesa** means the cope or surplice of a Buddhist priest. This vestment has very large lapels which are crossed diagonally on the chest. Hence the name of the 1st Immobilization.</sup>
>
> <sup>• [*My method of judo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a_G1AAAAIAAJ&q=%22kesa+gatame%22+buddhist), Mikinosuke Kawaishi (1955)</sup>

Comment: Incidentally, the same term is used for a diagonal sword cut in some circles of Kenjutsu.