# Etymology of Yama-Arashi?

Tags: judo, history, terminology, throwing, japanese

Most<sup>1</sup> Kodokan judo techniques are named in a somewhat systematised way, describing the major visual/mechanical components of the technique (e.g. *koshi-guruma* "hip wheel", *o-soto-gari* "major outer reap").  This is in contrast to the various impressionistic names of apocryphal techniques (e.g. *jigoku-jime, chōchin-datami, tama-guruma*).<sup>3</sup>

*Yama-arashi* (山嵐, "mountain storm") then seems something of an obtuse anomaly in the Kodokan syllabus.<sup>2</sup>

**What is the etymology behind *Yama-arashi*?**

Does it have anything to do with porcupines (also called [*yama-arashi*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B7), ヤマアラシ, 山荒 in Japanese)?

---

<sup>1. There are other more metaphorical, yet still penetrable, names: *tawara-gaeshi, [tomoe-nage](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9190/etymology-of-tomoe-nage), kani-basami, tani-otoshi, [kesa-gatame](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/why-is-a-scarf-hold-so-named-if-you-dont-wrap-around-the-opponents-neck-lik)*.</sup>
<sup>2. Along with a couple of others: *[tsubame-gaeshi](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9684/etymology-of-tsubame-gaeshi/), [kawazu-gake](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/origin-of-kawazu-gake)*.</sup>
<sup>3. With some being named for famous practitioners: *[tengu-nage](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9683/what-throw-is-tengu-nage), nanma-otoshi*</sup>

Comment: http://kodokanjudoinstitute.org/en/waza/digest/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yama-otoshi → Yama-arashi

*Yama-arashi* derives from an earlier jūjutsu throw *yama-otoshi*:

> Yama-arashi is recorded in Sekiguchi-ryu (the old style of jujutsu) as yama-otoshi.
>
> - [*Kodokan Judo Throwing Techniques*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=HGpbICBZdGwC&q=yama-otoshi) (p.78)

Thus it seems to have had an etymology similar to *tani-otoshi* originally, and given some added 'flair' at some point during its adoption into the go-kyo.

### Porcupines

Though the Japanese word for porcupine predates the judo throw by around two centuries,<sup>1</sup> the word was fairly obscure and (though pronounced the same) uses a different character for *arashi*,<sup>2</sup> hence the similarity is likely coincidental.

---

<sup>1. [*Japandemonium Illustrated: The Yokai Encyclopedias of Toriyama Sekien*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KkGjDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&lpg=PT24&dq=why+are+porcupines+called+yama-arashi) (p.298)</sup>
<sup>2. Although 嵐 is indeed [hypothesised to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B5%90#Etymology_1) derive from 荒らし etymologically.</sup>