# What is "Tengu-nage"?

Tags: judo, history, terminology, throwing, identification

Famous judoka Yokoyama Sakujirō was known by the nickname *Tengu*, and his [tokui-waza](http://www.sportsdefinitions.com/judo/Tokui-waza.html) was hence named *tengu-nage*:

> Yokoyama's specialty was *tengu-nage* ("mountain-devil throw"), said to be nearly on a par with Saigo's yama-arashi. It is not certain exactly what tengu-nage entailed. The name of the technique may be partly ascribed to Yokoyama's other nickname, "Tengu." Once, Yokoyama was traveling in the rural Hakone area. He met up with some rowdy porters and a fight ensued. Yokoyama thrashed them all so badly that they said to him, "What are you, some kind of tengu?" Yokoyama replied, "Yes, and I will be back if you don't behave yourselves!"
>
> - [*The Way of Judo: A Portrait of Jigoro Kano and His Students*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=L13P2hF33PUC&dq="tengu-nage")

What throw was this? Was it a novel throw he devised/adapted, or was it just a synonym for an existing throw he favoured?

Comment: Cruising the internet for quite some time and all I turned up with is that it may be some kind of yoko-sutemi-waza, since he allegedly preferred those in general. Maybe yoko-wakare? Don't think it was classified/named by then and would suit his build. Would also fit in with his relation to Mifune (who, IIRC, was the one classifying/naming it later on).

Comment: Possible further info: [*Hiden* (秘伝), "Tengu Nage" (May 1994, p.102-107)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=L13P2hF33PUC&pg=PT230&lpg=PT230&dq=%22tengu-nage%22)

Comment: Seen that one, too. Doesn't appear to be too helpful, though, since sources citing it - including the book itself - are still stating it to be unclear what throw it refers to, supposedly a judgement built on this source.

Answer (score 2):

Before entering the Kodokan, Yokoyama Sakujirō trained in *Tenjin Shin'yō-ryū* jūjutsu (as well as *Kitō-ryū*).

This school of jūjutsu taught a tachi-waza technique by the name of *tengu-shō*:

> The next listing is of a very famous similar school, the *Tenjin Shinyō Ryu* (天神真楊流).
>
> ...
>
> ### 天狗勝
>
> **Tengu Sho**
>   (Tengu No Kachi)
>   Goblin Victory
>
> - [*The Translation and Transcription of the Yōshin Shintō Koryū no Densho*](http://jtweymo.angelfire.com/YOSHIN_SHINTO_KORYU.pdf) (p.46, p.51)

Several Portuguese sites<sup>[1](http://sinesiorgomes.blogspot.com/2009/07/nage-waza-tecnicas-de-arremesso-aula-11_10.html) [2](https://judomododeusar.wordpress.com/2011/12/10/harai-goshi/)</sup> claim that *tengu-nage* was a synonym for *tengu-shō*, and that this technique was the progenitor of *harai-goshi*, introduced to the Kodokan by Yokoyama:

> Há duas versões sobre a origem desta técnica [*harai-goshi*]
>
> A primeira diz que Sakujiro Yokoyama tinha essa como seu golpe favorito, que era conhecido no jiu-jitsu como como tengu-nage ou tengu-shô, originária do estilo Tenjin-Shinyôryu, o qual estudava antes de entrar para o Kodokan.

As such, if this is indeed the origin of the throw, it would seem that Yokohama received his nickname for his use of it, and not vice versa, and that the story about him accosting some porters is apocryphal.