# Why do so many Japanese Martial Arts have a (different) technique called tsubame gaeshi?

Tags: technique, terminology, japanese

Japanese sword forms, Judo and Shorinji Kempo all have a technique called Tsubame Gaeshi (which roughly translates to swallow counter).

Why is the phrase Tsubame Gaeshi considered sufficiently important by the founder's of these three styles for them to name a technique this way?  According to this source https://japancraft.co.uk/blog/hidden-language-japanese-embroidery/ swallows are considered lucky amongst their other connotations.  Does the choice of name symbolise luck?  Or is it perhaps to do with how swallows fly?

Comment: This was covered in this answer: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9684/etymology-of-tsubame-gaeshi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Etymology of Tsubame-gaeshi?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9684/etymology-of-tsubame-gaeshi)

Comment: @SteveWeigand Only Partially.  I'm interested in where the sword forms got the name from.

Comment: I thought that link mentioned the sword form. Named after the quickly changing flight pattern of the swallow. Makes sense. You would start by looking like you're about to meet an attack head-on, but quickly change direction to evade, go past, and attack the now open opponent. A pretty common tactic in all martial arts and sports.